# Margin error or Gutter error while multiple page Printing in excel

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office, excel-365

Problem :
Margins are appearing when I print excel sheets when individual margin value is 0

Tools:
Excel 365
Panasonic DP-MB5445SX

Problem in detail:
I have 4 sheets to print, each sheet will fit an a4 size paper fully, I have given individual margins (Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Header & Footer margin value as 0)
The printer default margin value is also 0

Yet when I print all 4 sheets together Back to back, I am getting a 1 cm margin(either top or header) on all even pages (2,4)

Points to note:

1. If I print individual sheets and flip them manually then there is no margin error, print is exactly as required
2. In page setup there is no margin shown anywhere this is the same for all sheets
   [image: Page setup for individual sheets]
3. In printer properties margin is given as 0
   [image: Printer properties]

Any idea why this is happening? & how I could resolve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you use?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Hi, there is no code, I have done Cntrl + P and selected all sheets in workbook and given print option, after setting all margins and gutter as 0 but still am getting this error